# Compiling the Native Code with NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

when I am Trying to compile native C code like this:

```
:~/com.***.sample.ndk1$ ./ndk-build
Android NDK: Could not find platform files (headers and libraries)    
Android NDK: Please run build/tools/build-platforms.sh to build the corresponding      directory.    
/com.***.sample.ndk1/build/core/init.mk:345: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.

:~/com.***.sample.ndk1$ build/tools/build-platforms.sh
.: 39: Can't open build/tools/../core/ndk-common.sh
:~/com.***.sample.ndk1$
```

The above error is shows.

Could anyone answer to solve this problem?

Comment: :~/com.mamlambo.sample.ndk1$ build/tools/build-platforms.sh
.: 39: Can't open build/tools/../core/ndk-common.sh
:~/com.mamlambo.sample.ndk1$

Comment: Wait, what? You've installed the NDK into your project folder? Have you read this: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the Your NDK location directory to Your system `PATH` variable:
let suppose your ndk is in `/opt/android/android-ndk-r8b` folder, android sdk is in `/opt/android/android-sdk` folder
so, you may add the following lines to your `~/.bash_profile` (at the end of file) : 
`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android/android-ndk-r8b:/opt/android/android-sdk`

in addition You can run the following commands:

`chmod -R a+r /opt/android/android-ndk-r8b`

`chmod -R a+r /opt/android/android-sdk`